# Async Download file

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I plan to write a function DownloadData return a byte array, another client will call it to get byte array. My point is I don't want client app is waiting file is download, so I need it download in async mode. But I so confuse how to do that.
This is my function:

```
 public byte[] DownloadData(string serverUrlAddress, string path)
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serverUrlAddress) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
            return null;

        // Create a new WebClient instance
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        // Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
        string url = string.Concat(serverUrlAddress, "/", path);

        if (url.StartsWith("http://") == false)
            url = "http://" + url;

        byte[] data = null;

        client.DownloadDataCompleted += delegate(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            data = e.Result;
        };

        while (client.IsBusy) { }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: That `while` loop blocks..

Comment: what framework are you using? Looks like you are waiting until the download completes which defeats the purpose of doing it asynchronously

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a method that does just that.

```
    public async Task<byte[]> DownloadData(string url)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<byte[]> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync()))
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
            tcs.SetResult(ms.ToArray());
            return await tcs.Task;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @rezomegreldize the problem came from client, how do you call from client?

Comment: If you are allowed to use async/await try using the DownloadDataTaskAsync method of the WebClient class.

Answer (score 0):

I know why I lost byte. On API, I return byte array, but I use HttpClient to get data. I change to HttpResponseMessage as return and accept type on both.